# multiplication with insufficiently long registers

Tags: numeric-precision, product, arithmetic, register

I want to multiply two numbers but since I don’t have long enough registers in the current architecture need to “break them down” into shorter ones and somehow perform the calculation.

For example:

2048.125 x 2048.125 (2048.125 =>4001hex) but with the binary point beyond the 4th bit position (Q12.4 signed) and upwards .

Is there any way to split up the operation, and combine the results in the end?

Unfortunately the configuration am working on does not support well known libraries thus,I have to build one by myself.

Please provide any pointers that could lead to mathematical oriented implementation.Something that could possibly emerge out of manipulation of the partial products or similar.

Thanks

Comment: Google for *fixed point arithmetic*; perhaps use (in C) `long long`, or `int64_t`, or `__int128_t` if your implementation provides it). be aware of [big nums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).

Comment: Hint: How do *you* multiply two large numbers on paper, even though each "register" can only hold numbers 0-9? What if humans didn't have 10 fingers but 2**32?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch thank you very much for the reply,am aware about the 64 bit registers but unfortunately can not use them.The question is more of mathematical nature rather than language specific shortcuts.

Comment: @ Jörg W Mittag thanks very much for the pointer,maybe i didn't make myself clear,am looking for a way to split up the operation in two different registers,think it let say like keeping the integer parts in two registers and perform the multiplication then do the same with the fractional part and combine the result in separate registers.(Don't take this explanation for granted is not something legitimate just popped in my mind to picture what i want)

Comment: Let's try this again.  How do you multiply numbers in base 10? Now do the same with digits that are 8 bits, 16 bits or 32 bits in size.  It's ordinary arithmetic.

Comment: What exactly is your target processor architecture (& [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set)...)? Why do you code in assembler? Are you sure you don't have any available C99 compiler (it would support `long long`)? Please **improve your question** by editing it.

Comment: `(256A+B) * (256C+D) == (65536AC + 256(AD+BC) + BD)`

Comment: Read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) and the section that begins with the phrase *"To multiply two fixed-point numbers, ..."*.

Comment: Thank you @rwon, I know how to multiply fixed point numbers ,my problem is that I may lack of precision and I ask if there is a know method to break it down.

Comment: @GiwrgosRizeakos You have just named it in your question -  partial products ! To be frank I don't even know what it is that you *think* you don't understand, as it seems that you have already understood it.

Comment: To store the result, you don't simply attempt to evaluate `(uint)65536 * A * C)`, instead you simply evaluate `(uint16_t)A * (uint16_t)C` (knowing that A and C each can only be 8-bit, and then split up the `uint16_t` result into a high part (8 bits) and a low part (8 bits), and write each of them to two byte locations in the memory.

Comment: Thanks again for your effort...the problem arises when the A and C as you said are not 8 bits...or the binary point doesn't allow the operation due ot overflows...So I was thinking that it could possibly exist an operation that eg :takes half A (8 bits out of the 16) then half B (8 bits out of the 16)  work them out do something similar with the rest combine them and give back the result with the maximum precision.But as it seems is a rather trivial question...

Comment: @GiwrgosRizeakos: don't comment your own question but **edit your question** to improve it.

Comment: @GiwrgosRizeakos Computing devices that has less than 8 bit registers can only do [Binary Multiplication (digital design)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier)

Comment: @rwong the less than 8 bits example was just an attempt for clarification not an actual example.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid coding in assembler, and if possible adapt an existing C compiler to your target processor.

With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you have a lot of targets which could inspire you for your processor, and there are lots of documentation for that (see references in http://gcc-melt.org/docum.melt for more). Indeed it requires some effort (months of work).

Wide (but fixed size, e.g. two native `int`s -wide, such as 64 bits arithmetic on processors with 32 bits-wide words) arithmetic is done in GCC inside its [libgcc/](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libgcc/) directory, and most of that is coded in C (but depends a lot on how your GCC is configured and targeted). Even if you don't use or port GCC to your architecture (and I believe you really should), that `libgcc` should be inspirational (and IIRC, some books by Knuth explain the underlying algorithms, most of them being fairly intuitive.). Read also wikipage on [fixed-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic).

If you want arbitrarily large integers, you need a [bignum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library. Don't reinvent your own (there are many *tricky* algorithms more efficient than the naive way you have learned at school, and you'll find several books and many research articles and conferences on the subject; you still can get a PhD on bignums and spend a full work life on them). Use an existing one, e.g. [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/).

Even for your own target processor, you should not code much in assembler. You'll better port some existing C compiler to it (and practically you need one, if you want your processor to be used).

Comment: thank you Basile for your effort but as I highlighted above "The question is more of mathematical nature rather than language specific shortcuts".So what am asking effectively is of a mathematical oriented method to break down the operation instead of using the language's or library's capabilities.I am looking for a known algorithm to implemented myself because my current configuration does not allow none of the above.

Comment: Either you want fixed multi-word arithmetic, then look inside the algorithms of `libgcc`. Or you want arbitrarily large integers (bignums are a very complex algorithmic subject; there are many books on that, and you can get a PhD on the subject). Then better use an existing library